# If I Resolve a Conflict Does it Change Git Blame?

Tags: git, version-control, merge-conflict-resolution, git-blame

I'm trying to figure out whether a merge conflict was responsible for a bug, but I'm having difficulty because I'm not clear on how conflict resolution affects `git blame`.

Let's say I have a file in master:

```
a();
b();
c();
```

I modify it in master:

```
a();
d();
c();
```

but so does a co-worker, and they modify it differently, in a separate branch which they then merge in to master:

```
a();
e();
c();
```

Can resolving that conflict affect the blame?  In other words, if my co-worker resolves the conflict by going with my version:

```
a();
d();
c();
```

and I `git blame` the `d();` line, who will be blamed: me or my co-worker?

Similarly, let's say git got confused and thought both the first and second lines were conflicted:

```
<<<<
a();
d();
====
a();
e();
>>>>
```

If my co-worker resolves the conflict with their version:

```
a();
e();
c();
```

and I `git blame` the `a();` line, will I (the line's original author) get the blame, or will my co-worker (who "touched" it last, even though they didn't change it) get the blame?

Comment: You could probably create a test repository to test this out. Create a file in master. Create a new branch and change it. Switch back to master and change it. Merge and resolve the conflict and do a `git blame` on the file. In fact, you wouldn't even need a git server to host the repository.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I expect that `blame` would cite whoever *resolved* the conflict, since the resolution is then followed by `git add`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### tl;dr

If you run `git blame` on a merged file you are going to see the *original* author of each line, regardless of who did the merge commit. This means that if your co-worker decided to resolve the conflict using *your* version of the line, your name will be shown next to it.

#### Reconstructing the history of a file

In Git each commit holds two key pieces of information:

- A reference to a *snapshot* of your working directory at the time of the commit.
- A reference to the commit that came before it, aka its *parent*.

Given these two facts Git can reconstruct the history of changes occurred in a file by *walking backwards* from a given commit, generating at each step a diff between the current version of the file and its previous one.

This is exactly what `git blame` does. When you do `git blame` on a file, Git will reconstruct the history of the file on a *line by line* basis, showing you the author of the commit that introduced (i.e. *added*) each line.

#### Merge commits

A merge commit holds a reference to two parents:

- The commit referenced by the branch you *merged into*, aka the *left* side.
- The commit referenced by the branch you *merged*, aka the *right* side.

The snapshot contains all the changes from each side combined.

If you do a `git blame` on a *merge commit*, Git will walk two lines of history, one for each of the parent commits. Once Git reaches the commit whose snapshot *added* a certain line, it will show that commit's author next to the line.

#### Adding new lines when resolving a conflict

If a *new line* – that is a line that doesn't belong to either side of the merge – was added as part of a conflict resolution, that line would belong to the snapshot referenced by the merge commit itself. In that case `git blame` will report the author of the merge commit for that line.

Comment: Thank you, that was a perfect explanation and exactly what I was looking for!